# separate string into substring python

Tags: python, string, substring

how can I separate a string: "Blahblahblahblah" into "Blah" "blah" "blah" "blah" on python. I've tried the following:

```
str = "Blahblahblahblah"
for letter[0:3] on str
```

How can I do it?

Comment: try this code : `' b'.join(str.split('b'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not mind to use `re` library. In this example the regex `.{4}` means `any character except \n` of length 4.

```
import re

str = "Blahblahblahblah"
print re.findall(".{4}", str)
```

output:

```
['Blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah']
```

**Note:** `str` is not a very good name for a variable name. Because there is a function named `str()` in python that converts the given variable into a string.

Comment: You don't need the parens in the pattern string.

Comment: @ooga yes. you are right as its only one group here. I am updating the code.

Comment: I know you're keeping the same name as the OP, but `str` is *not* a good choice :) and `.` means *any* not newline character (unless told otherwise) - not *non-whitespace* char

Comment: @JonClements yes, you are right. I didn't notice that OP used `str` while doing copy/paste. I added a `note` for this.

Comment: I'm actually trying to separate RNA code into codons to analize the proteins of DNA.

Comment: @SAbuj You are wrong with the use of the word **whitespace**. In the doc of ``re``, whitespaces are defined as being the characters ``blank``, ``\f``, ``\n``, ``\r``, ``\t``, ``\v``

Comment: @user3501183 you may want to look at http://biopython.org then if you're dealing with that sort of data...

Comment: @eyquem yup... I've already mentioned that (in another way) :)

Comment: @Jon Excuse me, Jon. I instantly reacted when reading the message before reading the comments. My bad. By the way, I never understood if the commonly accepted meaning of the word **newline** is to designate only `\n`` or if it designates every kind of end of line as ``\n``, ``\r``, and ``\r\n``

Comment: @eyquem all good... just means the OP might decide to change it now :)  (update: and they have... fantastic)

Comment: @eyquem I updated my answer. Basically my previous quote was for `\s` and it was wrong. I updated it for `dot` now. I missed the part of one earlier comment that pointed this issue.

Comment: @Jon I don't understand what you mean by **(update: and they have... fantastic)**

Comment: @Sabuj I have another critic : what do you mean by **variable name** ? : _diverse name_ ? _variable's name_ ? The first means nothing. The second is horrid because there are no variables in Python, only names and objects.

Comment: @eyquem lol. I didn't know that there is no variable in Python. I thought its just like other languages. Can you please take a hand to update my answer?

Comment: In languages such as C++ and PHP, there are **variables** in the sense of **chunks of memory whose bits content can change**. In Python, the value of a non-container object can't change. The word **variable** in Python can have only the same sense as **name** and **identifier**. Since we already have at our disposal the synonyms **name** and **identifier** and the word **variable** is ambiguous and leads to miscomprehension of the _data model_ of Python, I don't see any interest to continue to use it in Python. Objects in Python are not variables they are complex C-structures.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
>>> SUBSTR_LEN = 4
>>> string = "bla1bla2bla3bla4"
>>> [string[n:n + SUBSTR_LEN] for n in range(0, len(string), SUBSTR_LEN)]
['bla1', 'bla2', 'bla3', 'bla4']
```